# BigQuery : how to build a new row based on duplicates

Tags: google-bigquery, duplicates, row

In BigQuery, I got this type of data below :

```
#standardSQL
WITH name_table AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, 1 hitnumber, 'alpha' page UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 2, 'beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 3, 'beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 4, 'alpha' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 5, 'beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 1, 'gamma' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 2, 'gamma'
 )
SELECT *
FROM name_table

 Output :
    id| hitnumber|  page 
    a |   1      |  alpha
    a |   2      |  beta 
    a |   3      |  beta 
    a |   4      |  alpha
    a |   5      |  beta
    b |   1      |  gamma
    b |   2      |  gamma
```

And I want to build a new hitnumber based on duplicate pages as below.

```
id| hitnumber|  page |  new_hitnumber
a |   1      |  alpha|  1
a |   2      |  beta |  2
a |   3      |  beta |  2
a |   4      |  alpha|  3
a |   5      |  beta |  4
b |   1      |  gamma|  1
b |   2      |  gamma|  1
```

Or if it's possible to deduplicate directly and obtain :

```
id| page |  new_hitnumber
a | alpha|  1
a | beta |  2
a | alpha|  3
a | beta |  4
b | gamma|  1
```

I tried with `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` but without success.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Arnaud

Comment: logic is not clear - you might want to add few more rows to your example or explicitly spell out the logic you have in mind

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant : thx for your comment, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to build a new hitnumber based on duplicate pages as below.

Use below approach

```
select * except(new_group),
  countif(ifnull(new_group, true)) over(partition by id order by hitnumber) new_hitnumber
from (
  select *, 
    page != lag(page) over(partition by id order by hitnumber) new_group
  from name_table
)
# order by id, hitnumber
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

> Or if it's possible to deduplicate directly

```
select * except(hitnumber) from (
  select * except(new_group),
    countif(ifnull(new_group, true)) over(partition by id order by hitnumber) new_hitnumber
  from (
    select *, 
      page != lag(page) over(partition by id order by hitnumber) new_group
    from name_table
  )
)
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by id, page, new_hitnumber order by hitnumber) = 1
order by id, new_hitnumber
```

in this case  - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works great. I have to take time to fully figure out your answer. LAG is a new function I discover. As you saw, I'm not an expert in Bigquery. Greetings from France